# PHP image resize function doesn't work properly?

Tags: php, image-processing, getimagesize

I am using this function to resize images but it causes an error

```
Call to undefined function resize()
```

Here is my source:

```
$w=280;
$h=280;
resize($w,$h);

function resize($width, $height)
{
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    /* calculate new image size with ratio */   
    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
    $folder="../images/";
    /* new file name  */   
    $path = $folder.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $update = mysql_query("update `detail` set `url` = '".$path."' where `id` = '".$id."'");
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,0, 0,$x, 0,$width, $height,$w, $h);
    /* Save image */   
    switch ($_FILES['image']['type']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($tmp, $path, 100);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($tmp, $path, 0);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($tmp, $path);
            break;
        default:
            exit;
            break;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Why do I get this error ?

Comment: Where is this code and how are you calling it?

Comment: You should not use mysql_query. It is depricated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Where does `$imgString` comes from ? What is the content of the  `$_FILE`-array ? You really have a lot problems to be solved in this case...

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with HTML, CSS and CakePHP, please use tags that are related to the problem. I've corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

Code error:Call to undefined function resize()

means it does not have access to that function.
If its in a different php file you have to include that first

```
include 'functions.inc.php';
```